# UIButton TouchUpInside sometimes not firing

Tags: ios, uibutton

I am creating UIButtons programmatically and set their targets as well. Most of the time TouchDown-TouchDragInside-TouchUpInside chain seems to work properly but if I perform this chain of events fast (about 2-3 times per second) method bound to TouchUpInside is sometimes not firing.

From my understanding UIEvents will always fire even if they don't fire immediately. Is this a known issue that I can't seem to find anything about? What can I do about it, besides touching things slower?

Comment: I don't quite clear what is you problem, is problem is occur with TouchUpInside only? I tested create button programmatically and log, and seem like it's work properly.

Comment: Is it possible that you are programmatically setting up your UIButton targets on a different thread than the touch event is picked up on?  Are you constantly changing the targets of these buttons? If this is the case, you may have a race condition.  However, in the scenario above, you would see the wrong targets being triggered not missing event firings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you create button  can switch and click.if so ,the two gesture will also do not handle well, you can add swipe gesture on the button , the it work well;Hope can help you.